# Jetpack Compose overscroll ripple effect

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there any way to show ripple effect when Column overscrolled?
I have added `Mofifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState)` to Column. It it impossible on latest compose version?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjCoI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The glow effect was added in 1.1.0-alpha03. It is present by default for scrollable columns and rows in that version and later.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.1.0-alpha03

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood that the effect is so-called "ripple effect". "glow effect" is correct, I will keep this in mind.